# Can't connect to ms sql database from docker container by sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, sql-server-express

I try to run a microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express container ->

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=password -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
```

And I get next error ->

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint
>   hopeful_kowalevski on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process
>   cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I think it is because sql server on my environment listens to 1433 port. 
Then I try to run container with other port eg 5000:1433 and container is run well.

Then I try to connect to db from container by sql management studio using "ip-address",5000. But I get Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258.

[image]

Comment: are you sure there is no firewall stopping you from using port 1433 (or 5000)

Comment: Yeah, there is no firewall stopping. I also added a new firewall rule for 5000 port. But it didn't help(

Comment: You have to add that rule at both ends. Just checking to be sure

Comment: What do you mean about both ends? Should I add the rule at the host and the rule in the container?

Comment: The firewall on the machine that is running this docker must allow that port, and also the firewall on the machine where you are trying to connect with the database must allow this port

Comment: I've configured the rule for 5000(Allow inbound and outbound) port on the host machine. The container with DB is also on this machine. And I run container on the host machine. But I can't connect to DB in the container.

Comment: Ok so we can rule out the firewall now. I had to check because 9 of out 10 that causes this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, the issue was with an incorrect password to DB. The password didn't match to database rules. The correct password should contain

> at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols ->
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash#pullandrun2017